# I have a blank line in my env command result

Tags: shell, unix, environment-variables, environment

Here is an extract of the result of env.

```
$ env
[...]
Apple_Ubiquity_Message=/tmp/launch-aPmDBq/Apple_Ubiquity_Message
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:91

MAVEN_OPTS=<some maven options>
PATH=<my path>
[....]
```

However, some library (some UIMA libraries) fails to work on my machine because of the blank line. Does somebody know how I can remove it?

EDIT: I can solve it in the terminal context by adding a line (see below) in the .bash_profile. However, the java library does not use the bash profile and the problem stays unsolved.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, `__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING` contains a trailing newline.  You can remove it with:

```
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=$(echo $__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING)
```

Comment: Thanks ! It works in the command line when I put it in my .bash_profile. However, since it is accessed with java through Runtime.getRuntime().exec("env"), it does not contain what is defined in the bash profile. How can I do it at a lower level than in the bash profile ?

Comment: Set the env variable when you run java:  `env __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=$(echo $__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING) java ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
sed '/^$/d' myFile
```